# Only reloading resolves without reloading html

Tags: angular-ui-router

How can i force ui router to reload the resolves on my state without reloading the entire ui/controller since

I am using components and since the data is binded from the state resolve,
i would like to change some parameters (pagination for example) without forcing the entire ui to reload but just the resolves

```
resolve : {
            data: ['MailingListService', '$transition$', function (MailingListService, $transition$) {
                var params = $transition$.params();
                var ml = params.id;
                return MailingListService.getUsers(ml, params.start, params.count)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        return {
                            users: result.data,
                            totalCount: result.totalCount
                        }
                    })
            }],

            node: ['lists', '$transition$', function (lists, $transition$) {
                return _.find(lists, {id: Number($transition$.params().id)})
            }]
        },
```

I would like to change $transition$.params.{start|count} and have the resolve updated without reloading the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you requested is not possible out of the box. Resolves are only resolved, when the state is entered.

But: one way of refreshing data could be, to check for state parameter changes in $doCheck and bind them to the components by hand.

**Solution 1**

This could look something like this:

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor($stateParams, MailingListService) {
    this.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    this.MailingListService = MailingListService;

    this.paramStart = null;
    this.paramCount = null;
    this.paramId = null;
    this.data = {};
  }

  $doCheck() {
    if(this.paramStart !== this.$stateParams.start ||
       this.paramCount !== this.$stateParams.count ||
       this.paramId !== this.$stateParams.id) {

      this.paramStart = this.$stateParams.start;
      this.paramCount = this.$stateParams.count;
      this.paramId = this.$stateParams.id;

      this.MailingListService.getUsers(this.paramId, this.paramStart, this.paramCount)
        .then((result) => {
          this.data = {
            users: result.data,
            totalCount: result.totalCount
          }
       })
    }
  }
}
```

Then you have no binding in the parent component anymore, because it "resolves" the data by itself, and you have to bind them to the child components by hand **IF** you insert them in the template of the parent component like:

```
<my-component>
  <my-child data="$ctrl.data"></my-child>
</my-component>
```

If you load the children via views, you are obviously not be able to bind the data this way. There is a little trick, but it's kinda hacky.

**Solution 2**

At first, resolve an empty object:

```
resolve : {
  data: () => {
    return {
      value: undefined
    };
  }
}
```

Now, assign a binding to all your components like:

```
bindings: { 
  data: '<'
}
```

Following the code example from above, where you resolve the data in $doCheck, the data assignment would look like this:

```
export class MyComponent {

  [..]

  $doCheck() {
    if(this.paramStart !== this.$stateParams.start ||
       this.paramCount !== this.$stateParams.count ||
       this.paramId !== this.$stateParams.id) {

      [..]

      this.MailingListService.getUsers(this.paramId, this.paramStart, this.paramCount)
        .then((result) => {
          this.data.value = {
            users: result.data,
            totalCount: result.totalCount
          }
       })
    }
  }
}
```

And last, you check for changes in the child components like:

```
export class MyChild {
  constructor() {
    this.dataValue = undefined;
  }

  $doCheck() {
    if(this.dataValue !== this.data.value) {
      this.dataValue = this.data.value;
    }
  }
}
```

In your child template, you access the data with:

```
{{ $ctrl.dataValue | json }}
```

I hope, I made my self clear with this hack. Remember: this is a bit off the concept of UI-Router, but works.

**NOTE**: Remember to declare the parameters as dynamic, so changes do not trigger the state to reload:

```
params: {
  start: {
    dynamic: true
  },
  page: {
    dynamic: true
  },
  id: {
    dynamic: true
  }
}
```